# $A_k$ is uncountable for some $k \in I$, then $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ is uncountable

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I come up with this theorem when I prove: If $A$ is uncountable and $B$ in non-empty, then $A \times B$ is uncountable. I found that proving this is not so hard by creating a bijection $f:A \times \{b\} \to A$ where $b \in B$ and notice that $A \times \{b\} \subseteq A \times B$. But I'm not sure if my proof for the generalization contains any error.

Please help me check the part that I define mapping $G$!

---

> **Lemma:** If $f:A \to B$ is surjective and $A$ is countable, then $B$ is countable.

The **Cartesian product** of a family $(A_i\mid i\in I)$ is defined as $$\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i=\{f:I\to\bigcup A_i\mid f(i)\in A_i \text{ for all } i \in I\}$$

> **Theorem:** Let $(A_i \mid i \in I)$ be the family of non-empty indexed sets where $A_k$ is uncountable for some $k \in I$. Then  $\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ is uncountable.

We define a mapping $G:\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i \to A_k$ by $G(f)=f(k) \in A_k$ for all $f \in \prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$. Then $G$ is clearly surjective. Assume the contrary that $\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ is countable. Then, by **Lemma**, $A_k$ is countable, which is a contradiction. Hence $\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ is uncountable.

**Update:** On the basis of Kavi Rama Murthy's and Saucy O'Path's comments, I added the proof that $G$ is surjective here.

By Axiom of Choice, there exists a mapping $f:I\to\bigcup A_i$ such that $f(i)\in A_i$ for all $i \in I$. For any $a \in A_k$, we define a mapping $f_a$ by $f_a(i)=f(i)$ for all $i \neq k$ and $f_a(k)=a$. Then $f_a$ is clearly in $\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ and $G(f_a)=a$. Hence $G$ is surjective.

Comment: Perfect! Your proof is valid (assuming Axiom Of Choice). However, you have assume that $A_i$'s are all  non-empty. If some $A_i$ with $i\neq k$ is empty then the product will become empty!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have added that $A_i$ is nonempty for all $i \in I$ :) Of course, we must appeal to Axiom of Choice when dealing with $I$ in general.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have asked a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907637/define-a-countably-infinite-subset-of-x for several days, but have not received any answer. Although I have some questions that are not answered such as this one. I'm very in need of getting an answer for this question. Could you please help me check it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claiming that $G$ is surjective is a slightly delicate matter, because it requires you to prove that for all $u\in A_k$ there is a function $f:I\to \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ such that $f(i)\in A_i$ for all $i\in I$ and $f(k)=u$. This is certainly false if $A_i=\emptyset$ for some $i\ne k$ (and the entire thing **is false** in that instance). Giving a proper argument for the case where $A_i\ne \emptyset$ for all $i$ is tantamount to the axiom of choice.

Comment: I have added that $A_i$ is nonempty for all $i \in I$ :) Of course, we must appeal to Axiom of Choice when dealing with $I$ in general.

Comment: Please check my argument that $G$ is surjective! By Axiom of Choice, there exists a mapping $f:I\to\bigcup A_i$ such that $f(i)\in A_i$ for all $i \in I$. For any $a \in A_k$, we define a mapping $f_a$ by $f_a(i)=f(i)$ for all $i \neq k$ and $f_a(k)=a$. Then $f_a$ is clearly in $\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ and $G(f_a)=a$. Hence $G$ is surjective.

Comment: It is perfeclty fine.

Comment: Thank you so much ^^

Comment: Hi @Saucy I have asked a question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909659/let-a-be-a-subset-of-bbb-n-without-a-greatest-element-then-there-exists-a for several days, but have not received any answer. Could you please help me check it out?